# I have a text that I would like to increment specific numbers in it. How can I do this on ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu

~/Documents/filesForTraining/audio/Female_Audio/001/001_Yoruba_Female_headsetMic_0001.wav,~/Documents/filesForTraining/transcriptions/Female_transcription/001/001_Yoruba_Female_headsetMic_0001.txt
~/Documents/filesForTraining/audio/Female_Audio/001/001_Yoruba_Female_headsetMic_0002.wav,~/Documents/filesForTraining/transcriptions/Female_transcription/001/001_Yoruba_Female_headsetMic_0002.txt
~/Documents/filesForTraining/audio/Female_Audio/001/001_Yoruba_Female_headsetMic_0003.wav,~/Documents/filesForTraining/transcriptions/Female_transcription/001/001_Yoruba_Female_headsetMic_0003.txt

I want to increment the numbers before the .wav extension and the .txt extension

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with python, I would recommend a python script that does the following:

1. Split your string using space as a delimiter.
2. Loop over that list to again split those strings, but using "," as delimiter.
3. Flatten that list.
4. Loop over the list and check if they contain .wav or .txt using regex.
5. If so split the string on ".", which will yield a list with two strings:

   1. Split the first string on "_".
   2. This will leave you with the part you want to increment as the last element of that list.
   3. Use `lstrip("0")` and read that string using `int(yourstr)`.
   4. Increment your int.
   5. Execute zfill(4) on your string to add back the leading zeros.
6. Reconnect all split strings with the correct seperators and print the result.